# Problems to use python unittest mock properly

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, mocking, python-unittest

I have difficulties to implement unit tests for my python project. I've done unit testing without mocking but this time it's not possible because of SSH.

Here's one of my scripts what I'm currently trying to unit test:

```
import os
from helpers.ssh_connection import SshConnection


class Certificates:
    def get_certificates(self, env_name):
        try:
            stdin, stdout, stderr = SshConnection().execute_cmd("get certificate_1")
            certificate_1 = stdout.read().decode("utf-8").strip()
            stdin, stdout, stderr = SshConnection().execute_cmd(f"get certificate_2 by using {env_name}")
            certificate_2 = stdout.read().decode("utf-8").strip()
            print(certificate_1, end="\n\n")
            print(certificate_2)
            return True

        except RuntimeError:
            msg = "Unable to run script for certificate list"
            print(msg)
            return False

    def main(self):
        environment = os.environ['IP_ADDRESS']
        ssh_key = os.environ['SSH_KEY_PATH']
        env_name = os.environ['ENV_NAME']

        SshConnection().open_connection(environment, ssh_key)

        print("Certificates")
        print("============")
        Certificates().get_certificates(env_name)
        SshConnection().close_connection()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Certificates().main()
```

And here's what I have tried but my coverage is less than 20% and I can't figure out how to increase it:

```
import os
import unittest
from unittest import mock

@mock.patch('certificates.Certificates')
@mock.patch('helpers.ssh_connection.SshConnection')
class TestCertificates(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_certificates(self, MockCertificates, MockSsh):
        certs = MockCertificates()
        env_name = "env"

        certs.get_certificates(env_name)
        certs.get_certificates.assert_called_once_with(env_name)
        certs.get_certificates.return_value = True

        result = certs.get_certificates(env_name)
        expected = True
        self.assertEqual(expected, result)

    def test_main(self, MockCertificates, MockSsh):
        certs = MockCertificates()
        ssh = MockSsh()

        mock_env_vars = mock.patch.dict(os.environ, {"IP_ADDRESS": "123.123.123",
                                                    "SSH_KEY_PATH": "ssh_keys/ssh",
                                                    "ENV_NAME": "env")

        mock_env_vars.start()

        ssh.open_connection(os.environ["IP_ADDRESS"], os.environ["SSH_KEY_PATH"])
        ssh.open_connection.assert_called_once_with(os.environ["IP_ADDRESS"], os.environ["SSH_KEY_PATH"])
        certs.get_certificates(os.environ["ENV_NAME"])
        certs.get_certificates.assert_called_once_with(os.environ["ENV_NAME"])
        certs.get_certificates.return_value = True

        result = certs.get_certificates(os.environ["ENV_NAME"])
        expected = True
        self.assertEqual(expected, result)

        ssh.close_connection()
        mock_env_vars.stop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Please help me to understand how to use mock properly. Thank you very much!

Comment: You are mocking away the very class that you want to  test. You should decide which parts you want to test, and mock the parts that you don't want to test.

Comment: I want to mock only SSH component because that's the only dependency to this script. I still haven't figured out how. I just don't understand the way how mock is acting even though I've read documentations million times..

Comment: In this case you should only mock `SshConnection` and remove the other mock. Also note that you are not mocking it correctly - in your module, you do `from helpers.ssh_connection import SshConnection`, meaning that you have to mock `SshConnection` _in your module_, e.g. something like `@mock.patch('certificate.SshConnection')`, provided that `certificate.py` is where `Certifcate` lives. See also [where to patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#id6).

Comment: After creating patch is this the right way how to use mock class: `ssh = MockSsh()` and then I can set return values for the mock functions e. g. `ssh.open_connection.return_value = True`

Comment: `MockSsh.return_value.open_connection.return_value = True`.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I managed to get better coverage by following your advice and everything is working smoothly.